# Routing with ipsec tunnel

Tags: routing, ipsec

We are trying to determine how to route traffic from our office 1 worker subnet through the office 1 server subnet over the IPSec tunnel to our office 2 server subnet.
We want the office 2 worker subnet to pass through the office 2 server subnet to reach the office 1 server subnet.
The attached image demonstrates that the server subnets are capable of communicating through the IPSec tunnel at present.
The challenge is that the systems on the worker subnets can talk to their server subnet fine, but they can't talk to the servers in the other office subnet.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

[image: Network diagram]

Routing table

```
1      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0          x.x.x.x            WAN           0
    
2      X.X.X.X          255.255.255.0      0.0.0.0          WAN             0

3    10.10.1.0        255.255.255.0    0.0.0.0          office_srv2 0 

4      192.168.1.0      255.255.255.0      0.0.0.0          office_wrk2 0

x.x.x.x = public ip of office 1 router with ipsec endpoint
```

Comment: Draw a network diagram showing where routers are situated. That's more useful.

Comment: The routers are at the edge of each network. They define both server and office nets.

Comment: What does the routing tables look like on each side?

Comment: You can see the routing table here: https://gist.github.com/drewmace/e082bde6ccbb23c72abbade3ede4289c

Comment: What kind of router do you have?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to configure a static route on the router of office2 that has as destination office1 with the vpn gateway.
[image]

And the same on the router of office1

I would set up a direct tunnel between the worker subnets, because you want to avoid double hop

Edit:
And in terms of security purposes I wouldn't recommend opening up a whole office subnet to a server subnet. I think a better solution would be to install a VPN client for the users that need server access,and only letting the people that need access to the server connect to the server subnets using a VPN.

Comment: There's no double hop. There's a single router at each location with two subnets.

Comment: But in the current setup it looks like there is a tunnel between the server subnets and the office subnet is behind that, if you are going to connect the office subnets together all traffic goes to the server subnet first and then over the tunnel. If I'm correct, from the office subnet you have then the hop of the server subnet and the tunnel

Comment: *The routers are at the edge of each network. They define both server and office nets.* according to comments. No extra hop.

Comment: We want the office 2 worker subnet to pass through the office 2 server subnet to reach the office 1 server subnet.

Comment: Doesn't make sense given a single router. There's no double hop.

Comment: And for security purposes I wouldn't open up a whole office subnet to a server subnet

Comment: Huh? Use a firewall to restrict traffic.

Comment: Yeah that's also an option but what I tried to explain is Network segmentation/Micro segmentation as part of zero trust

Answer (score 2):

Each router needs to have a route to all required subnets.

From what I can make out from the routing table from the Office1 router(?) you posted, it's missing a route to 192.168.1.0/24 through the tunnel - both routes should use the same tunnel/interface/gateway. Without that explicit route, packets go the default route, out to the Internet.

Likewise, the Office2 router requires explicit routes to 192.168.6.0/24 and 192.168.7.0/24 through the tunnel.

You can either set up static routes or use a routing protocol like OSPF between your routers (if supported).

Since you're using IPsec, make sure that the SAs permit traffic between those subnets.